# BIND not pointing to right IPs

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns, dns-hosting

This is more of an experiment to learn and understand BIND/NAMED more but here is what I have.

I set my computers DNS to my linux server's IP. I have BIND9 running with the following entry:

```
$TTL    1 @     IN      SOA     1.2.3.4. google.com. (
                              2013041602                ; Serial
                              1         ; Refresh
                              1         ; Retry
                              10000             ; Expire
                              1 )       ; Negative Cac
home       14400   IN      A       1.2.3.4
*       14400   IN      A       2.2.2.2
space     14400   IN      A       1.2.3.4


1.2.3.4 = My Server IP
```

If I ping home.google.com I get nothing from my computer at home. If my DNS is pointed to a BIND9 server, shouldn't it take those DNS records?

This is on the server(does Windows have a dig?)

I edited /etc/resolv.conf to use my Linux server as the DNS.

```
dig home.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> home.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 2032
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;home.google.com.     IN      A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 1.2.3.4#53(1.2.3.4)
;; WHEN: Wed Apr 17 10:00:59 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43
```

NSLOOKUP:

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  1.2.3.4

*** UnKnown can't find home.google.com: Server failed
```

---

named.conf

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

named.conf.options:

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

         forwarders {
                75.75.75.75;
                75.75.76.76;
         };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

named.conf.local

```
zone "google.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.google.com";
};

zone "2.3.4.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        notify no;
        file "/etc/bind/db.192";
};
```

/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones

```
zone "localhost" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.local";
};

zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.127";
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.0";
};

zone "255.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.255";
};
```

Comment: `ping` is a horrible tool for troubleshooting DNS. Post the output of `dig home.google.com`.

Comment: Done. Does Windows have a dig?

Comment: Windows has `nslookup`.

Comment: Added with Windows.

Comment: You can not use a wildcard on the root entry of your domain. Other than that, this is impossible to troubleshoot without seeing your BIND config.

Comment: What should I include. named.conf and all of it's files?

Comment: If you have a `SERVFAIL`, you should have a look at your `syslog` and eventually look up the error you find there.

Comment: @pauska Wildcards in the root of the domain are allowed.  CNAMEs are not.

Comment: If bind encounters an error in a zone file, it logs an error in the log file and finishes loading the rest of the zones but ignores *all* of the zone with the error, leaving you with `SERVFAIL` responses for that zone.  You can use `named-checkzone` on your zonefiles and `named-checkconf` on your conf to check the syntax and other rules before restarting.

Comment: Dig is included with BIND.  If you have BIND you should have dig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two *very* different things: a DNS server can be a *resolver* (receiving names from all the possible domains and resolving them by asking the authoritative name servers of the world) or an *authoritative server* (serving data about your own zones to resolvers). I strongly advise to keep the two separate (on different machines). Otherwise, debugging is really painful.

You configuration seems OK for an authoritative server for the domain google.com except that dig's output show that recursion is available. You should disable it (`recursion no;`).

The next step is to check that the zone was indeed loaded by the name server. Remember, Unix system administration is looking at log files all the day. Check the log file for named startup messages, you will probably find an error message explaining why the zone was not loaded (alternatively, test the zone with named-checkzone).